# Add relationship to three tables with data and strange column names

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a Postgres database with 3 tables with data and their models in Django. I do not have control over how these tables are filled. But I need to add relationships to them.

It would not be a problem for me in MsSQL, Oracle or MySql. But Im confused here.

```
class Keywords(models.Model):
     id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     keyword = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=250)

class Mapping(models.Model):
     id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     keyword = models.CharField(max_length=250)
     videoid = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Video(models.Model):
     videoid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model `Mapping`, which is used to relate with the models `Keywords` and `Video`, you can make changes like:
     `class Mapping(models.Model):`

```
      id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  
      keyword = models.ForeignKey(Keywords, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      videoid = models.ForeignKey(Video, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You also don't need to define id for the model as Django itself creates a id field which is auto generated and primary key.

Comment: Keywords and Mapping are connected not via ip field, but by textfield. This is where Im stuck.

Comment: I think where Im confused is that I need to relate already an existent table with a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

Use [inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb) in order to generate your models from your db tables.

```
$ ./manage.py inspectdb table1 table2 table3 >> models.py
```

### Relation

```
 class Video(models.Model):
      #...
      keywords = models.ManyToManyField(Keywords)
```

Then you can remove the Mapping model, the table for this relation is generated by Django.

If you want to keep the data of the already related instances, use the `through` key parameter for the ManyToManyField with the Mapping model.

Comment: this is done, that is how the models are generated. There are no relations in DB as well. i want to add them via migrations

Comment: I've updated the answer, according the models you have, the relation would be a Manu to many between Video and Keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution:

```
class Mapping(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    video = models.ForeignKey(Videos, to_field='videoid', db_column='videoid', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,blank=False,null=True,)
    keyword = models.ForeignKey(Keywords, to_field='keyword', db_column='keyword', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=False, null=True,)
```

To add relations to existing tables with weird column names and type it is the best to use **to_field** and **db_column**. In this case, Django will not try to create standard id columns for relations.